# Maven latest version installation UBuntu 16 without using "wget"

Tags: linux, maven, ubuntu, devops

Is there any way to install latest Maven specific version without using wget command in ubuntu 16.

Comment: Download it some other way?

Comment: which part are you trying to avoid, the wget or the manual management of maven versions and paths?

Comment: You don't like the one installed by "sudo apt install maven"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing what my link below recommends, but add references to Bionic instead of Xenial. Then all you need to do is `sudo apt install maven`.

Note the current version of support Maven for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) is 3.6.0-1, so if that isn't new enough for you (the latest Maven release is 3.6.2), you'll have to find another way.

https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/how-to-install-packages-from-a-newer-distribution-without-installing-unwanted-6584fa93208f

Answer (score 0):

you could install [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) on the machine 1st and then use it to install and manage various java-related tools (maven among them), but [installing sdkman itself](https://sdkman.io/install) likely involves a wget